# How to undo Preview Node Output in Shader Editor?

Tags: shader-nodes

I've discovered a useful shortcut for previewing a Shader node by Ctrl+Shift+LMB on the node. Nice! Problem: How do I undo the preview? The Blender manual doesn't explain how. I've seen other references that say Ctrl+Shift+LMB again on a blank area in the node editor will do it, but that doesn't work for me. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.6

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_wrangler.html

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out: Ctrl+Shift+LMB on the Principled BSDF node will undo the preview.

Comment: CTRL + Z? 

Comment: Ctrl+Z works, but that's assuming you haven't done other operations after enabling the preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've seen other references that say Ctrl+Shift+LMB again on a blank area.

That is in the Geometry Nodes Editor. 
You can click in a blank area to disable the Viewer Node. Just selecting the node once again or previewing another thing makes it active once again.

In the Shader Editor however, there is no viewer node. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> connects the node output directly to the Active Output. So if you just want to preview the final node, you simply have to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> on the final node.